# Como disparar múltiplos erros em uma só verificação de dados usando C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção

Estou criando uma solução onde gostaria de manter todas as regras de negócio dentro de meus *models* inclusive a resposta à erros. O problema é que eu também gostaria de poder capturar múltiplos erros de uma só vez assim:

```
public class Usuario
{
    private int idade;
    public int Idade
    {
        get => idade;
        set
        {
            if (value < 18)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("O usuário precisa ter mais que 18 anos.");

            idade = value;
        }
    }

    private string senha;
    public string Senha
    {
        get => senha;
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) || value.Length < 6 || value.Length > 50)
                throw new ArgumentException("A senha deve ter entre 6 e 50 caracteres.");
            senha = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Preciso que ao fazer uma nova instância desse usuário e alimentasse essas informações, que eu possa retornar todos os erros referentes a implementação do modelo para que, esses possam ser usados para informar ao usuário do *model* (que pode ser uma API, uma *view*, ou qualquer outro), assim:

```
public class PropertySetError
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T>
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PropertySetError> InvalidProperties { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("/usuario")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Response<Usuario>>> postUsuario([FromBody] JObject obj)
    {
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        object temp = null;
        Response<Usuario> response = new Response<Usuario>();

        try
        {
            foreach(var prop in typeof(Usuario).GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    obj.TryGetValue(prop.Name, out temp);
                    prop.SetValue(usuario, Convert.ChangeType(temp, prop.GetType()));
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            response.Status = true;
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Status = false;

            // ... pega todos os possíveis erros aqui e passa para a resposta

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    obj.TryGetValue(prop.Name, out temp);
    prop.SetValue(usuario, Convert.ChangeType(temp, prop.GetType()));
}
catch (Exception) {
    throw;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/Forward.cs).

Isto não faz sentido, capturar uma exceção só para lançá-la de novo é algo errado. Se não tem nada útil para fazer com a exceção não a capture. A outra captura até está correta, mas evite capturar `Exception`, quase sempre isto é um erro.

Antes de usar exceção eu estudaria mais o seu uso. [Tem muitas coisas aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50). As pessoas abusam de criar lançar e principalmente capturar exceções, neste caso certamente.

Eu não sou fã de lançar exceção nesses casos, mas sendo uma propriedade fica complicado fazer validação de outra forma. E espero que seja só um exemplo ruim, por fora da faixa não foi feita para o que foi usado, ali é um erro de argumento também.

O fato de querer pegar várias exceções já é um indicativo que este não é o mecanismo correto.

Mas talvez, e só talvez, possa estar querendo usar a [`AggregateException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Também considero o uso da reflexão neste caso exagerado, você deve ter essas informações em tempo de compilação, é muito mais fácil, robusto e rápido usá-las, ainda que tenha que digitar algo mais.

Comment: entendi, bom a ideia é que eu possa usar as classes de modelo em qualquer lugar e centralizar todas as regras de negócio nelas mas, também poder validar tudo de uma vez invés de ficar chamando um erro por vez.

Comment: agora que li mais sobre AggregateException  realmente é isso que eu procurava!